# I am getting (TypeError: Cannot read property 'down' of undefined)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a style file that has

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paperStyle: {
    width: 400,
    height: 320,
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    [theme.breakpoints.down("xs")]: {
      width:200
    },
  },
  animationStyle: {
    width: "90%",
    height: "90%",
  },
}));
```

I feel everything is correct, I am not understanding why is this giving me that error? Where am I going wrong?
Has something changed in the Alpha version of material-ui? Please help.

Here is the link for [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-banach-oxpjt?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Well `theme.breakpoints` is undefined. You can do an if check for a quick fix

Comment: There is no problem with `theme.breakpoints` the problem is with down.

Comment: I removed `down('xs')` and there was no error.

Comment: use import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### maybe try replacing

```js
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";
```

##### with

```js
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
```

Comment: This gives me `Attempted import error: 'makeStyles' is not exported from '@material-ui/core/styles'.` error

Comment: @Satyam Please can you try with `import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core;`

Comment: `Attempted import error: 'makeStyles' is not exported from '@material-ui/core'.` this is the error now

Comment: `import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";` this doesn't give any error. It works fine when I remove that part where there is down.

Comment: I did open your sanbox and replaced `import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";`
with `import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";` and works fine. Take a look  [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-frog-upv2m?file=/src/App.js:70-124)

Comment: @AnuragParmar Thank you!! the problem was with the version `material-ui/core@5.0.0beta` has a problem with imports. That is why I got the error!!
Can you specify the version in your answer?. I'll accept your answer. Once again thank you!!

Comment: **Material ui: 4.12**

 You can check version of all dependencies in this [package.json](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-frog-upv2m?file=/package.json:191-337)

**You're Welcome**